# Content Security Policy 'unsafe-eval': How to avoid using eval() in javascript jquery.timer.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, eval

How to avoid using eval in line 10 of the following jquery.timer.js?

The reason to get rid of the eval is because my site is moving to CSP and requires 'unsafe-eval' now.

Perhaps there is an alternatives to eval() for this use-case.

I am kind of stuck. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
;
(function($) {
    $.timer = function(func, time, autostart) {
        this.set = function(func, time, autostart) {
            this.init = true;
            if (typeof func == 'object') {
                var paramList = ['autostart', 'time'];
                for (var arg in paramList) {
                    if (func[paramList[arg]] != undefined) {
                        eval(paramList[arg] + " = func[paramList[arg]]");
                    }
                };
                func = func.action;
            }
            if (typeof func == 'function') {
                this.action = func;
            }
            if (!isNaN(time)) {
                this.intervalTime = time;
            }
            if (autostart && !this.isActive) {
                this.isActive = true;
                this.setTimer();
            }
            return this;
        };

        (...)
        this.setTimer = function(time) {
            var timer = this;
            if (typeof this.action != 'function') {
                return;
            }
            if (isNaN(time)) {
                time = this.intervalTime;
            }
            this.remaining = time;
            this.last = new Date();
            this.clearTimer();
            this.timeoutObject = window.setTimeout(function() {
                timer.go();
            }, time);
        };
        this.go = function() {
            if (this.isActive) {
                this.action();
                this.setTimer();
            }
        };
        if (this.init) {
            return new $.timer(func, time, autostart);
        } else {
            this.set(func, time, autostart);
            return this;
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I read through https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3541, but still in the weeds.

Comment: Can you link to the original plugin documentation? Frankly I'd recommend finding another library entirely, as anything that uses `eval()` is showing a marker against the dev who created it.

Comment: The site includes a version without a clear reference. I searched on the web and found the version that corresponds with my site: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/91864370/. I realize now that this script is outdated. The more recent version on github https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer/blob/master/jquery.timer.js has no eval(). I am going to test this version, to see if it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although painstaking and error-prone if `paramList` is large, you could manually set the variable values **given that the `paramList` is not created dynamically**.

For `autostart` and `time`, you would use the following:

```
if(func['autostart'] != undefined) {
    autostart = func['autostart'];
}

if(func['time'] != undefined) {
    time = func['time'];
}
```

Note that this solution relies entirely on the fact that you know the contents of `paramList` ahead of time.

In the context of the code you provided, you would modify `this.set` like so:

```
this.set = function(func, time, autostart) {
    this.init = true;
    if (typeof func == 'object') {

        /* Modified Code */
        if(func['autostart'] != undefined) {
            autostart = func['autostart'];
        }

        if(func['time'] != undefined) {
            time = func['time'];
        }
        /* End Modified Code */

        func = func.action;
    }
    if (typeof func == 'function') {
        this.action = func;
    }
    if (!isNaN(time)) {
        this.intervalTime = time;
    }
    if (autostart && !this.isActive) {
        this.isActive = true;
        this.setTimer();
    }
    return this;
};
```